# Facebook live_videos not authorized

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

Okay so my problem is that I am trying to create a program that will start livestreaming for you automatically. In order to do this, I need to send a POST request to the endpoint at 
`/{user-id}/live_videos?access_token={access_token}` but the post request does not have the required permissions for some reason, even though it does. It should return me the stream ID and endpoint, but the only thnig I'm getting in response is

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "(#200) App does not have permission to create live video on this user",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 200,
        "fbtrace_id": "AScLE9Q72KR"
    }
}
```

a goddamn permission denied. Any tips on how to resolve this kind of problem? I am totally lost and have been for a couple of days already now.

The permissiosn for my app are as follows:
[image]

Comment: Posting to `/{user-id}/{access_token}` is just nonsense, I am pretty sure it doesn’t say anywhere that you should do that.

Comment: @CBroe Sorry, was a typo from me. It was supposed to say `/{user-id}/live_videos?access_token={access_token}`